# Regedit GPO to control its behaviour

Tags: gpo

Is there anyway that I can control the behaviour of Regedit with its relevant values/keys via group policy? To controls the behaviour of web and application links within outlook?

Please see the above.

Comment: Are you asking how to set a registry value via group policy?

Comment: Yes Correct I am asking for that --- Can you advise

Answer (score 0):

Registry settings are under

"Computer Configuration" or "User Configuration" > "Preferences" > "Windows Settings"

[image: Registry option in the tree of settings in the group policy editor]

Right click on the white space and go to "New" > "Registry Item" (if you want to manually create the registry entries) or "Registry Wizard" (if you want to copy registry settings from another computer)

[image: adding a new registry item from the right-click menu]

That said, you will probably have a better time if you use the [ADMX templates for Office](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030) as opposed to trying to find the right registry settings yourself.